# Typescript keyof self

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a type that can use the typeof it's own keys and can't seem to find a solve. Here is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do:

```js
type SpecialType = Record<string, (getter: <K extends keyof SpecialType>(key: K) => ReturnType<SpecialType[K]>) => any>

const yo: SpecialType = {
  a: get => {
    get('b') // ok, should return type string
    return 1 // returns number
  },
  b: get => {
    get('a') // ok, should return type number
    get('c') // should error
    return 'a' // returns string
  }
}
```

The type I have defined doesn't actually work as intended. I am looking for the `get` parameter for each of those functions to be restricted to the keys of the parent object, and ideally be able to know the return type of that function based on which key they use in `get`.

My current line of thought is something like;

```js
type SpecialType<T extends Record<string, (getter: <K extends keyof T>(key: K) => ReturnType<T[K]>) => any>> = T
```

But this doesn't work without the user specifying the generic themself (which I am trying to avoid)

Comment: I really don't see a way to get the compiler to infer this for you; it's too circular... or rather, it needs to know the return types of all the properties before it can infer the argument types of the properties, but the normal inference doesn't proceed in that order... at least not outside of classes.  I could imagine coming up with a type where you have to write `{a: number, b: string}` somewhere and it would work, but that might be too manual for you.  Maybe someone can figure out a way to convince the compiler to infer your types, but I haven't done so yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish something similar using [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and taking advantage of [how `this` works in Javascript](https://javascript.info/object-methods#this-in-methods). When you define functions inside an object, `this` is automatically scoped to the containing object, like this:

```
const specialType = {
  get a() {
    this.b; // string
    return 1; // returns number
  },
  get b(){
    this.a; // number
    return 'a'; // returns string
  },
};
```

This is how people defined classes before ES6 introduced the class keyword. Does this do what you want?

Comment: No, I see where you are going, but I simplified my example quite a bit. In my actual use case the `get` method I am passing to each function is a bit more involved.

I am looking for a way to accomplish exactly what I outlined with typescript